# Flutter, use DynamicLibrary.open() on prebuild GO .so library without the need to write Native Code(Java/Swift)

Tags: go, flutter, dart, shared-libraries

I made a GO library and build it as an .so library. Is working loading the library in Java with `System.loadLibrary()` but I can not manage it to load directly from flutter/dart using `DynamicLibrary.open()`.

I want to skip the process of calling native code, and load Shared Libraries directly in flutter.

`DynamicLibrary.open` is only available on dev channel v1.10.14.

Documentation with examples using Cmake:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop

My code:

```
static final DynamicLibrary nativeAddLib = DynamicLibrary.open("lib-mylib.so");
final int Function (String ifName, int tunFd, String settings) addStuff = nativeAddLib.lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(String, Int32, String)>>("addStuff").asFunction();
```

Error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/vpn_connection/vpn_connection_bloc.dart:20:164: Error: Expected type 'NativeFunction<Int32 Function(String, Int32, String)>' to be a valid   and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
- 'NativeFunction' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'Int32' is from 'dart:ffi'.
final int Function (String ifName, int tunFd, String settings) addStuff = nativeAddLib.lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(String, Int32, String)>>("addStuff").asFunction();
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
#0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system  /targets/dart.dart:226:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:526:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget.<anonymous closure>   (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:481:35)
#3      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#4      AsyncMemoizer.runOnce (package:async/src/async_memoizer.dart:43:45)
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:481:21)
```

It looks like is not finding the file/function.

My gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDirs += files(extraJniDirectory)
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.custom.android"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        ndk {
            if (project.hasProperty('target-platform') &&
                    project.property('target-platform') == 'android-arm64') {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            } else {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Update:**

I created a .so file with CMake as in the flutter example, I extract it from the apk and put it in the same folder with my go build .so file, and is working, but I can't find why my first .so file is not working from flutter but, is working from android.

**Update2:**

`DynamicLibrary.open("lib-mylib.so")` is loaded,
`nativeAddLib.lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(String, Int32, String)>>("addStuff")` is returning a pointer, that means the function is found, but when calling `.asFunction()` it breaks.

By simplifying the code:

```
var addStuff = nativeAddLib.lookup("addStuff").asFunction();
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Expected type 'NativeType' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
- 'NativeType' is from 'dart:ffi'.
```

Comment: Hi, where do you put `.so` file in android. And what is `extraJniDirectory`? I have the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem might be that Dart's FFI doesn't directly support Strings. Have a look at this sample for a way to marshal strings using the separate ffi package: https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/blob/master/ffi/system-command/linux.dart

Comment: I will give it a try, I don't think is from String support, because I tried with different methods which are accepting Int32 and not returning(void).

Comment: If you paste the code & error messages from the simpler Int32 example that might help. void is actually similar to String - one needs to use a special ffi.Void type in the native typedef.

Comment: Glad that helped! I sure hope they improve the error messages soon..

Answer (score 0):

static final DynamicLibrary nativeAddLib = DynamicLibrary.open("lib-mylib.so");
final int Functionhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/14ybJn0InIjjo2EQI9-ghltEW8FyhiPjy/view?usp=drivesdklib-mylib.sohttps://drive.google.com/file/d/14xXJGZN0wKGBaxZNDoNvefj_XEe9EU3W/view?usp=drivesdkstatic final DynamicLibrary nativeAddLib = DynamicLibrary.open("lib-mylib.so");
final int Functionstart javaw -jar ${application.title}.jar</echo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).